# how to export a dataframe to latex with some minimal formatting?

Tags: r, latex, xtable, stargazer

Consider this simple example

```
library(dplyr)
dataframe <- data_frame(mytext1 = c('HELLO',
                                   'WORLD'),
                        mytext2 = c('HELLO',
                                   'AGAIN'),
                        value1 = c(1,2), 
                        value2 = c(1,2))

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  mytext1 mytext2 value1 value2
    <chr>   <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1   HELLO   HELLO      1      1
2   WORLD   AGAIN      2      2
```

I would like to export this dataframe to a latex table, but with some little (but important) tweaks.

In particular, I would like, in the latex output, to add *a supercolumn* that separates the text variables and another that separates the numeric variables. That is, something in the spirit of `mat` and `com` in this image:

[image]

I tried the R packages `xtable` and `tables` but I was unable to achieve something close (likely because they create summary statistics tables). Am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using `kable` from the `knitr` package plus the `kableExtra` package:

````
```{r table, results='asis'}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(magrittr)

dataframe <- data.frame(mytext1 = c('HELLO',
                                   'WORLD'),
                        mytext2 = c('HELLO',
                                   'AGAIN'),
                        value1 = c(1,2), 
                        value2 = c(1,2))

dataframe %>%
    kable(format = 'latex', booktabs = TRUE) %>%
    add_header_above(header = c("Text" = 2, "Values" = 2))
```
````

Here I've shown the code included in an RMarkdown chunk, where the table is automatically included when knitting to PDF, but the code should also work on its own outside of RMarkdown.

Running the code by itself you get the Latex code for the table as output:

```
\begin{tabular}{llrr}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Text} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Values} \\
\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){1-2} \cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){3-4}
mytext1 & mytext2 & value1 & value2\\
\midrule
HELLO & HELLO & 1 & 1\\
WORLD & AGAIN & 2 & 2\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Thanks Marius! but I would like to get a latex table so that I can include in my main `tex` file

Comment: Yes, as I said this works outside of RMarkdown as well, it outputs the latex code for the table.

Comment: haha wonderful!!! do you know if there is an option to remove the `begin{tabular}` and `end{tabular}` line?

Comment: Doesn't look like it, there a few different options to use plain table, booktabs or longtable but I don't think there's an option for suppressing those.

Comment: Marius, please have a look here. I think its worth another question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45929671/how-to-edit-the-content-of-a-kable-file