# How to save and edit the content of a kable print?

Tags: r, dplyr, latex, knitr

This is a follow-up to [how to export a dataframe to latex with some minimal formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45929263/how-to-export-a-dataframe-to-latex-with-some-minimal-formatting/45929340#45929340)

Consider this working example

````
```{r table, results='asis'}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(magrittr)

dataframe <- data.frame(mytext1 = c('HELLO',
                                   'WORLD'),
                        mytext2 = c('HELLO',
                                   'AGAIN'),
                        value1 = c(1,2), 
                        value2 = c(1,2))

piper <- dataframe %>%
    kable(format = 'latex', booktabs = TRUE) %>%
    add_header_above(header = c("Text" = 2, "Values" = 2))
```
````

which gives

```
\begin{tabular}{llrr}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Text} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Values} \\
\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){1-2} \cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){3-4}
mytext1 & mytext2 & value1 & value2\\
\midrule
HELLO & HELLO & 1 & 1\\
WORLD & AGAIN & 2 & 2\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Here I would like to write this output to a `tex` file, and remove manually the first and last line of it.

Unfortunately, the naive

```
piper  %>% filter(row_number() >=2 & row_number() <=(length(piper) - 1))
Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "knitr_kable"
```

does not work here. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you are working in a .Rmd file, see this on keeping the intermediate .tex file, which you can edit manually and then recompile. http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#keeping_intermediate_tex

Comment: thanks @meenarapan but I am using a regular script

Comment: So you mean remove manually within the R script rather than in your tex file?

Comment: I just mean I want to save the tex table to a tex file, while removing its first and last line (the ones with begin tabular and end tabular) thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you print `piper`, you're actually calling a print method which makes a lot of changes.  `piper` isn't just those 10 lines of text.

If you want to get those lines, you can call `capture.output(piper)`, and you should be able to filter that as a character vector.  I don't think the `row_number()` function works on those, but regular indexing should.  For example,

```
lines <- piper  %>% capture.output
lines[c(-1, -length(lines))]
```

Edited to add:  To print that without line numbers, use `cat()`.  For example,

```
lines[c(-1, -length(lines))] %>% cat(sep = "\n")
```

Comment: thanks that very nice but there is a problem. The output of capture output looks like `[1] ""                                                            
 [2] "\\begin{tabular}{llrr}"                                      
 [3] "\\toprule"                                                   
 [4] "\\multicolumn{2}{c}{Text} & \\multicolumn{2}{c}{Values} \\\\"` ... how to obtain the proper tex content without the line number and the extra `\\` ?

Comment: `lines[c(-1, -length(lines))] %>% cat(file="path/to/myfile.tex",sep = "\n")`